# What are the units tracking resource usage for the S0 Azure SQL Database?

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database

This is in regards Azure accounts on the 12 months trial that come with free services.

The free services include a SQL Server Database using the DTU model in tier S0. The exact terms are stated here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq/

When it comes down to the actual tracking in the Azure Portal, the blade at **subscription/overview** shows some indicators but the units are confusing / missing.

I had no luck finding a clear response online on what this metric could mean. It seems to me the metric was recently changed.

**> What is the metric "2.54/31 (1/Day)" measuring exactly?**

Images below showing specific case with current usage.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "2.54/31 (1/Day)"

That means you've used 2.54 of the 31 free days of Azure SQL Database S0 that you get for free each month.  But since S0 is a provisioned service tier, this is not a variable, usage-based meters like many of the other billing meters.  More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/check-free-service-usage).